# How to combine ScaleAnimation and moving of view using layout() function

Tags: android, animation, android-framelayout

I'm trying to implement dragging on Android.

I have FrameLayout as an area, where draggable views (tiles) are moving.
When user touches tile it should become bigger. For this need I'm using `ScaleAnimation` with zero duration **to support platforms below 11** (where `setScaleX` and `setScaleY` functions are added). And for tiles moving i'm using `layout(...)` function.

The problem is bad redrawing of moving tile. Seems like it's cropped to initial bounds while moving.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at http://nineoldandroids.com/. They have created a library that supports (the much easier) ObjectAnimator, for all devices! Have a look at 'translateX' and 'translateY' for your draggable tiles. Good luck

Comment: @Entreco I've added this library to my project. It seems to be very useful. Now I have the same code for all platforms. But dragging (scaling via ObjectAnimator + dragging via layout() function) for device with Android 2.3.7 is still buggy, it looks the same as before.